# How to update data on Mysql using extjs4 grid update option

Tags: php, extjs4

Hi everyone i am working on  small data update section using direct grid example the problem is i am not able to update the data using the cell plugin ,i am able to do add and delete and it has direct update to db but when i edit the existing field it does not shows any error and updates on the screen and i did not see any POST response on network area or console of chrome i don't why its not happening

here are the codes please help

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);

    //added model inside onready
    Ext.define('PersonalInfo', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['id', 'name', 'address', 'state','st_one','st_two','st_three','st_for']
    });

    //separated store into unique var for guaranteeRange
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id: 'store',
        model: 'PersonalInfo',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'direct',
            api: {
                create:QueryDatabase.createRecord,
                read:QueryDatabase.getResults,
                update:QueryDatabase.updateRecords,
                destroy:QueryDatabase.destroyRecord
            }
        }
    });

    var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
        autoCancel: false

    });


    var alphaSpaceTest = /^[-\sa-zA-Z]+$/;

    Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
        //  vtype validation function
        alphaSpace: function(val, field) {
            return alphaSpaceTest.test(val);
        },
        // vtype Text property: The error text to display when the validation function returns false
        alphaSpaceText: 'Not a valid state.  Must not contain numbers.',
        // vtype Mask property: The keystroke filter mask
        alphaSpaceMask: /^[-\sa-zA-Z]+$/
    });

    // create the Grid
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        //height: 550,
        //width: 800,
        cls: 'grid',
        title: 'Production Planning Control',
        store: store,
        columns: [{
            dataIndex: 'id',
            width: 50,
            text: 'ID'
        }, {
            dataIndex: 'name',
            flex: 0.5,
            text: 'ClientName',
            //pt 2
            allowBlank: false,
            field: {
                type: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        }, {
            dataIndex: 'address',
            flex: 0.5,
            text: 'Product Name',
            //pt 2
            allowBlank: false,
            field: {
                type: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        }, {
            dataIndex: 'state',
            flex: 0.8,
            text: 'No Of QtyRequired',
            //pt 2
            allowBlank: false,
            field: {
                type: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false,
                //vtype: 'alphaSpace'
            }
        },{
            dataIndex: 'st_one',
            flex: 0.7,
            text: 'Station 1',
            //pt 2
            allowBlank: false,
            field: {
                type: 'textfield',
                //allowBlank: false,
                //vtype: 'alphaSpace'
            }
},
            {
            dataIndex: 'st_two',
            flex: 0.7,
            text: 'Station 2',
            //pt 2
            allowBlank: false,
            field: {
                type: 'textfield',
                //allowBlank: false,
                //vtype: 'alphaSpace'
            }
        },{
            dataIndex: 'st_three',
            flex: 0.7,
            text: 'Station 3',
            //pt 2
            allowBlank: false,
            field: {
                type: 'textfield',
                //allowBlank: false,
                //vtype: 'alphaSpace'
            }
        },
            {
            dataIndex: 'st_for',
            flex: 0.7,
            text: 'Station 4',
            //pt 2
            allowBlank: false,
            field: {
                type: 'textfield',
                //allowBlank: false,
                //vtype: 'alphaSpace'
            }
        }

        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        //pt 2
        plugins: [
            rowEditing
        ],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            store: store,
            dock: 'bottom',
            //creating, add items
            items: [{
                iconCls: 'add',
                text: 'Add',
                handler: function() {
                    rowEditing.cancelEdit();
                    // create a record
                    var newRecord = Ext.create('PersonalInfo');
                    store.insert(0, newRecord);
                    rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);

                    // write about this section in tutorial
                    var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
                    grid.on('edit', function() {

                        var record = sm.getSelection();
                        store.record.commit();
                        //store.sync();
                        //e.record.commit();
                        //store.commitChanges();
                        store.remove(record);
                        store.load();
                        store.sync();
                        alert ('dome');




                    });
                }
            }, {
                iconCls: 'delete',
                text: 'Delete',
                handler: function() {
                    rowEditing.cancelEdit();
                    var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
                    Ext.Msg.show({
                         title:'Delete Record?',
                         msg: 'You are deleting a record permanently, this cannot be undone. Proceed?',
                         buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                         icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
                         fn: function(btn){
                            if(btn === 'yes') {
                                store.remove(sm.getSelection());
                                store.sync();
                            }
                         }
                    });
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                iconCls:'refresh',
                text: 'Refresh Grid',
            //  action: 'refresh',
                handler:function(){
                    //var reload=this.getGridPanel().getStore();
                    store.load();
                }

            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `autoSync:true` store config to have it post automatically.

Comment: But where do we have to use it like here @dbrin

`code`var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
  clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
  autoCancel: false,
  autoSync:true
 });

Comment: autoSync is a store property.

Comment: sorry i tried not working ....its like i am able to post data in db somehow but when i want to edit it and then updates it just updates on the screen and then when reloads data would be same@dbrin

Comment: do you now see a post on when you edit ? and comment out your add handler for now it s doing a whole mess of things it shouldn't.

Comment: yeah it does after adding `autoSync:true` in the store and it post's this `{"type":"rpc","tid":2,"action":"QueryDatabase","method":"updateRecords","result":null} @dbrin`

Comment: yeah but the thing is its posting null data i think and not updating anything after the refresh!!! @dbrin

Comment: By the way 'field' config is depricated in favor of 'editor' http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-field

Comment: turns out to be an issue actually now its doing something buggy i suppose!!